# Как сделать массив объектов нескольких классов?

Tags: java, ооп

Необходимо...
В приложении создать массив объектов Product-(Book, Shoe,Toy, Picture) , состоящий из количества элементов заданного параметром.
имеется 4 класса book shoe toy picture.

делаю вот так

```
Shoe Product[] = new Shoe[4];
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    Product[i] = new picture();
    Product[i] = new Shoe();
    Product[i] = new Book();
    Product[i] = new toy();  
}
```

Но как правильно сделать?

Comment: Можно вообще одной строкой: `Product[] products = {new Picture(), new Shoe(), new Book(), new Toy()};` индексация начинается с нуля, следовательно `products[2]` будет экземпляр класса `Book`.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Product[] products = new Product[4];
products[0] = new Picture();
products[1] = new Shoe();
products[2] = new Book();
products[3] = new Toy();
```

В вашем коде есть несколько ошибок:

1. Судя по всему, `Product` является базовым классом или интерфейсом, а `Picture`, `Shoe`,
   `Book`, `Toy` -- его наследниками. Для того, чтобы поместить в один
   массив экземпляры разных классов, массив должен иметь в качестве
   элемента некоторый базовый тип -- `Product` в вашем случае.
2. На каждой итерации цикла вы четырежды присваиваете i-му элементу
   массива разные объекты, в результате у вас получается массив из
   четырех экземпляров класса `Toy`.

Answer (score 5):

```java
public interface Product {/* ... */}
public class Picture implements Product { /* ... */ }
public class Shoe implements Product { /* ... */ }
public class Book implements Product { /* ... */ }
public class Toy implements Product { /* ... */ }

List< Product > products = new ArrayList< Product >();

products.add(new Picture());
products.add(new Shoe());
products.add(new Book());
products.add(new Toy());
```

Comment: Здесь, наверное, логичнее будет абстрактный класс и наследование от него, чем имплементация интерфейса. `Product` может содержать методы общие для всех потомков, а вообще согласен - коллекция более гибкий инструмент для такого рода данных, чем примитивнй массив

Comment: К сожалению контекст задачи не указан в вопросе. Конечно можно и абстрактный класс. Все зависит от задачи.

Answer (score 1):

Можно так:

```
Picture picture = new Picture();
Shoe shoe = new Shoe();
Book book = new Book();
Toy toy = new Toy();
Product[] products = new Product[]{picture, shoe, book, toy};
```

При условии, что Product является суперклассом для вышеперечисленных классов